# Method being called both statically and non-static, works and doesnt

Tags: php

This code works fine:

```
<?php

class Test {

    public function hi($data) {
        $instance = !(isset($this) && $this instanceof self) ? new static() : $this;
        echo "HI!!! ".$data."\n";
        return $instance;
    }

    public function log($data) {
        $instance = !(isset($this) && $this instanceof self) ? new static() : $this;
        echo "Log: ".$data."\n";
        return $instance;
    }
}

Test::log("HI THERE!");
(new Test())->log("how are you?");

Test::hi("1")->hi("2");
(new Test())->hi("3")->hi("4");
```

Returning:

```
Log: HI THERE!
Log: how are you?
HI!!! 1
HI!!! 2
HI!!! 3
HI!!! 4
```

But this one doesn't:

```
class AL extends Model
{

    public function event($verb, $data = [])
    {
        $static = !(isset($this) && $this instanceof self);
        $instance = $static ? new static([ 'verb' => $verb ]) : $this;

        if(!empty($data)) $instance->data($data);

        $instance->save();
        return $instance;
    }
```

When calling:

```
    AL::event($verb, $product);
```

It fails, returning:

> [ErrorException]
>
> Non-static method App\Model\AL::event() should not be called statically

I am using:

```
PHP version: PHP Version => 7.1.8-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4
```

the only difference between the two calls is that I do the first one calling `php test.php` and the second one calling Laravel's artisan command line interface.

¿What can be the cause of the inconsistency?

Comment: The cause is most likely your error reporting setting in your php.ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official PHP documentation:

> **Warning** In PHP 7, calling non-static methods statically is deprecated, and will generate an **E_DEPRECATED** warning. Support for calling non-static methods statically may be removed in the future.
>
> *[PHP: Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), emphasis original*

This means that you *can* call a non-static function statically, but php will throw a notice. Here however, this noticed is being converted to an `ErrorException` (most likely by the parent `Model` class), causing the execution of the code to stop. Since your first example doesn't extend from the class `Model` it still works fine.

Comment: Oh, that's it then... I tried turning on the "E_STRICT" error reporting level, but it still didn't report.  I wasn't aware of "E_DEPRECATED". Thanks!